# Will C++17 template arguments with auto feature allow constrained std::function objects?

Tags: c++, templates, auto, c++17, std-function

With the upcoming C++17 feature of [non-type template arguments with auto](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0127r1.html), will it be possible to implement `std::function` in such a way as to be able to put, for example, the following functions:

```
    bool f(int n,  double d) {}    
    bool g(bool b, char c)   {}
    bool h(bool b)           {}
```

into auto-templated `std::function` objects:

```
   std::function<bool(auto,   auto)> faa = f; // ok
   std::function<bool(int,    auto)> fia = f; // ok
   std::function<bool(double, auto)> fda = f; // error: function type mismatch
   std::function<bool(auto,   auto)> gaa = g; // ok
   std::function<bool(auto,   auto)> haa = h; // error: function type mismatch
   std::function<bool(auto)>         ha  = h; // ok
```

And so on.

In other words, to have `std::function` objects *constrained on the function types they accept*?

(Currently, on GCC we get an `error: 'auto' parameter not permitted in this context`.)

Comment: How would you call a `std::function<bool(auto,   auto)>`, assuming such a thing exists?

Comment: @n.m.: Very, very carefully.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit as opposed to the usual sloppy calling of pre-C++17 functions?

Comment: @n.m.: Of course!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those are not non-type template arguments, so `auto` is not permitted there in C++17.

Non-type template arguments are arguments to templates that are pointers or integers or similar, actual values, not types.

For an example,

```
std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 7>;
```

here the `7` is a non-type template argument of type `std::size_t` and value `7`.

Non-type template `auto` permits something like:

```
template<auto x>
using integral = std::integral_constant< decltype(x), x >;
```

now `integral<7>` is `std::integral_constant<int, 7>`.

On the other hand, your use of `auto` is in place of a *type*, not a non-type.

---

There is a feature where the type of the template is deduced, so you could write:

```
std::function faa = f;
```

if they augmented `std::function` to be able to deduce a signature from a function pointer (or non-template callable).

Note however that this `std::function` would have a fixed signature, not a template one.  The feature simply allows *deduction*, not template dynamic dispatch.

I don't know if `std::function` was augmented in this way in C++17, but the language feature to do so was added.

Comment: *"template dynamic dispatch"* oh lord... I hope that this thing never exists

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot Simply ship a compiler, an abstraction of source, and require the caller provide the same for the template arguments passed in.  Compile it and memoize the compilation during dispatch.  Easy-peasy!  Scripting/bytecode languages do it all the time (usually with less power than C++ templates).